# Can't figue out why the value didn't change

Tags: c#, inheritance, encapsulation

I'm new to OOP and C#.

I've tried to use inheritance and encapsulation concepts and get stuck.

Can't figue out why a Deposit method din't work when i call it through Atm_1 class.

---

***parent class***

```
  class Atm
  {

    public int TotalBalance { get; private set; } = 1000;

    public Atm() { }

    public void DepoSit(int deposit)  { TotalBalance += deposit; }  

  }
```

***child class***

```
  class Atm_1:Atm 
  {

  }
```

***main***

```
 class Program
 {

    static void Main()
    {


        var atm = new Atm();
        var atm_1 = new Atm_1();

       //Before Deposit 
        Console.WriteLine("Total Balance is "+atm.TotalBalance);     //1000

        //Deposit
        atm_1.DepoSit(20);

        //After Deposit
        Console.WriteLine("Total Balance is " + atm.TotalBalance);   //Still 1000 ??



        atm.DepoSit(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Balance is " + atm.TotalBalance);   //Now 1500
        //This Works -why the above didn't work?  

    }
}
```

Comment: It's clear from the code why the code does what it does. But it's _not_ clear why you thought anything different would happen. Why do you create two different objects? Why do you think a change in one object (`atm_1`) will affect the other object (`atm`)? Inheritance is about the _type_, not the instances, and modifying one instance of a type that has inherited the type of a different instance isn't going to have any effect on that different instance.

Comment: I would like to create atm_2, 3,4 and so on. And I wan't to store the combine value of all atm in TotalBalance

Comment: I suggest to review basic concepts of OOP. In particular it seems that you need to understand what an instance of a class is.

Comment: _"I would like to create atm_2, 3,4 and so on"_ -- so what you actually need is an array of `atm`, i.e. `atm[]`. _"I wan't to store the combine value of all atm in TotalBalance"_ -- the `TotalBalance` property is a non-static member of the `atm` class, so each instance of `atm` will have its own `TotalBalance` value. If you want the sum of the instances, you can do that simply by iterating over the array and adding each of the instance values. If you want to track the total in real-time as you modify each instance, that's more complicated.

Comment: It really helps!  I never thought of an array in my head. Thanks a lot Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Atm_1` inherited the property `TotalBalance` , constructor `Atm()`, and method `DepoSit(int deposit)` of `Atm`, but not the data you set to `new Atm();`.

`Atm_1` and `Atm` are two different instances of the same class. Try to visualize your objects `Amt_1` and `Amt` as variables, setting one variables data doesn't change the others data.

Answer (score 0):

> > From **Peter Dunniho** Comments, I can figure out what i need to do is to create an array instead. Thanks for all comments and answers :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Atm[] atm = new Atm[3];

        atm[0] = new Atm(50);
        atm[1] = new Atm(100000);
        atm[2] = new Atm(25);

        int totalBalance=0;

       for( int i=0;i<atm.Length;i++)
        {
            totalBalance += atm[i].Balance;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("TotalBalance is "+totalBalance.ToString("c"));


        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}



class Atm
{
    public int Balance { get; private set; }

    public Atm(int balance)
    {
         Balance=balance;
    }

}
```